# Getting last Saturday from a given date using jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am trying to get the last Saturday from a given date. If function argument is `9/12/2019` it should return `9/7/2019`.

I have tried two methods below with no success:

```js
function getLastSaturday(theDate) {
  debugger
  var dateToUse = new Date(theDate);
  var lastSaturday = new Date(new Date().setDate(dateToUse.getDate() - (dateToUse.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : dateToUse.getDay() + 1)));
  return lastSaturday;
}

function getLatestSaturday(theDate) {
  var dateToUse = new Date(theDate);
  var latestSaturday = new Date(new Date().setDate(dateToUse.getDate() - dateToUse.getDay() + 1));
  return latestSaturday;
}

console.log(getLastSaturday('9/12/2019'));
console.log(getLatestSaturday('9/12/2019'));

console.log(getLastSaturday('8/5/2019'));
```

**Update**

*Modified getLastSaturday(theDate) that works*

```
function getLastSaturday(theDate) {
    var dateToUse = new Date(theDate);
    var start = dateToUse.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : dateToUse.getDay();
    var target = 6; // Saturday

    if (target >= start)
        target -= 7;
    var lastSaturday = dateToUse.addDays(target - start);
    return lastSaturday;
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Your first example works fine.

Comment: when I test it, I select 8/5/2019 and it return 9/3/2019. The date that I get from an Ajax call and pass to this function is of the form `Mon Aug 05 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` i.e. the parameter `theDate`

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638906/get-date-of-specific-day-of-the-week-in-javascript/3639224 wouldn't be too difficult to modify one of the answers to fit your needs.

Comment: Helpful, I will try to see if I can use DateJS library. I think my problem is the format of the date I get from Ajax; if i can convert `Mon Aug 05 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` to `08/05/2019` I think I can use my first function

Comment: I was able to use DateJS library to resolve this, thanks to @user7290573. Makes it very simple, all I had to do was take the date returned from Ajax call (`dtWeekStart`) and use `dtStart = dtWeekStart.last().saturday();`. If you make your comment into a response, i will mark it as answer.

Comment: I have also updated my first JS function to return the same result although DateJS is much easier.

Comment: I think you should post an answer to your own question as it sounds like you've found a couple of solutions that worked for you. Glad to have pointed you in the right direction, though!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the line:

```
var lastSaturday = new Date(new Date().setDate(dateToUse.getDate() - (dateToUse.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : dateToUse.getDay() + 1)));
```

This gets the current date, then subtracts the day number of some other date. All you need to do is subtract the date's day number + 1, e.g.

```js
function getLastSaturday(date) {
  // Copy date so don't modify original
  let d = new Date(date);
  // Adjust to previous Saturday
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - (d.getDay() + 1));
  return d;
}

// Samples
[new Date(2019,8,23),
 new Date(2019,8, 1),
 new Date(2019,8, 7),
 new Date(2019,8,12)
].forEach(d => console.log(d.toString()
  + ' => ' +  getLastSaturday(d).toString()
));
```

Also see [*get previous saturday's date and next friday's*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019024/get-previous-saturdays-date-and-next-fridays).

Using the built–in parser for unsupported string formats is strongly recommended against, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

The date format "9/7/2019" is ambiguous, it represents 9 July to most people or 7 September to some. The simplest way to avoid confusion is to use the month name rather than number.

Comment: so how would we avoid the ambiguity based on internal date formats?

Comment: @chovy—what are "internal date formats"? There are 3 formats required to be supported by ECMA-262, anything else is implementation dependent so might return either an expected, unexpected or invalid date. There is some *de facto* standardisation on common US formats, but that should not be relied on.

Comment: sorry, meant to say "international" not "internal"